# Is there a risk of injection using mail function

Tags: php

Hi 
I'm developing a contact form. I'm using the mail function to email it over to the webmaster.

Is there a risk someone could inject malicious javascript and any other injection attack?

```
$to = (this is from config xml file)
$message = $_POST['message'];
mail($to ,'feedback',$message);
```

Answer (score 3):

Only if you set the content type to `text/html`

Answer (score 0):

If [registers globals](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) are ON (which should NOT be) there is a (huge) risk of injection (**depending on where `$to` is really set**).

Also as David pointed out you could sanitize $_POST['message'] if you use HTML messages (maybe with [htmlspecialchars](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)).

Comment: Why is this voted down? I'm not a PHP expert and rather want to learn what's wrong with this answer.

Comment: @Marcel Korpel I guess it's because in this exact case ($to is always setted) registers globals is not a problem. I was just pointing out that this is a possibility with the actual OP code and not the pseudo code posted.